# saving empty field in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, database, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, database-schema

i would like to add possibility to erase content of the cell and save the empty field. I tried to define my field in parameter update map like this:

```
((data.Value) ? '","Value": "' + data.Value : "") +
```

and in schema like this:

```
"Value": { 
   type: "number", 
   parse: function (value) { 
       return (value === null || undefined) ? null : value; 
   }, 
   nullable: true 
},
```

but I always get the last saved value. I tried to change it in few ways but still doesn't work, either it saves null as a string or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let kendo.stringify do the work for you. You just have to set nullable: true (as you have already done). You don't need the parse.

Checkout http://dojo.telerik.com/ORudo - try editing the UnitsInStock to null and hitting Save Changes - notice that the UnitsInStock value is null.